# jQuery- call a function/method before submitting a form with js or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-analytics

I am trying to call google analytics event tracking method before submitting a form on this [page](http://tinyurl.com/cykjdp5)

This is the code that I have now:

```
$(function() {

    $('#findbooking input').each(function(){
        $(this).blur(function() {

          if (!$(this).val()) {
              _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Rebooking', 'completed', $(this).parent().parent().text()]);
              dcsMultiTrack('WT.ac', 'See_and_Change_my_booking_completed');
          } else {
              _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Rebooking', 'skipped', $(this).parent().parent().text()]);

          }
       });
    });
});
```

The problem is that the dcsMultiTrack request is fired twice when the user blur from each input field. It is supposed to only send the request once.

Note: We don't have access/modify the source code and the code will be placed on the same page as a workaround. Any help is highly appropriated

Comment: Can you how us a little bit of your markup for input tags or maybe it's a standard input field, without default value?

Comment: @KristianVitozev: please check the page here: http://tinyurl.com/cykjdp5

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint to see what the call stack is each time?

Comment: I can't find the above code on that page.

Comment: @Barmar: I didn't try the breakpoints. The code is injected by Google Tag manager and exists at the end of the page. I have tested on Google chrome dev as well by fireing the code and check the request in network tab

Comment: I set a breakpoint in `dcsMultiTrack`, it only stopped once after I left each input field.

Comment: @Barmar: How did you set the breakpoint ? can you please elaborate ?

Comment: I use Chrome Developer Tools, go to Sources tab, select the saswtscript.js file, find the dcsMultiTrack function, and click on the first line in the function to set a breakpoint. Other browsers have similar debuggers, the exact details will vary.

Comment: @Barmar: Thank you but do you mean I will have to set a breakpoint in my code sample ?

Comment: I'm just saying that I don't see the problem you described. `dcsMultiTrack` isn't being called twice on each blur, and that's how I determined it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) handler to track the form submission event. The callback is invoked prior to the actual form submission, so you can place your tracking logic there. This approach guarantees that the tracking events are fired only once, not every time a user moves focus from one form field to another.

If I undestood your note correctly, the function you gave is an external script you don't have access to, and you are going to override it placing script directly on the page. In this case you need to remove the handlers previously attached to `blur` events. `$('#findbooking input').unbind('blur');` will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you so much. if you check the source code in that page, it is built with ASP.Net and the form is built with tables and 2 input fields and is submitted with a js function by binding an event when clicking on submit button.